# How to have a good url?

Tags: php

I trying to develop a new bank module. The bank has an API and when I send the following URL as a parameter in a request made to the bank's API:

```
https://www.example.net:443/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho
```

it then returns a response URL containing the outcome of the request as URL parameters, however the bank's API assumes that the URL provided does not already have a query string and simply appends a new complete query string including the `?` to the input URL (for example) `?TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018%5fa%5f11%3a32%3a28&monta`, making the final URL:

```
https://www.example.net:443/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho?TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018%5fa%5f11%3a32%3a28&monta
```

However due to the extra `?` character, when I redirect a user to this URL, my server interprets `$_GET['ho?TPE']` as a single variable `"monet14"` instead of `$_GET['ho'] = ""` and `$_GET['TPE'] = "monet14"`. When I redirect the remote user to this URL, they are then redirected to `index.php` instead of the desired script.

Here is the output of `var_dump($_GET)` after redirecting the user:

```
array(23) { 
    ["order"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["desjardins"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["success"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["ho?TPE"]=> string(7) "monet14" 
    ["date"]=> string(21) "12/07/2018_a_11:32:28" 
    ["montant"]=> string(5) "53EUR"
}
```

Instead I would like the user to be redirected to:

```
 https://www.example.net:443/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho&TPE=monet14
```

How can I change the extra `?` to an `&` in the URL returned by my bank's API before redirecting the user?

Comment: I rewrote your question so that it makes more sense based on [your comment on a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867996/rebuild-url-n-php?noredirect=1#comment90689851_51867996).

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you're probably looking for [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Here's an example of how to parse, manipulate and combine two queries to one query:

```
// These are the two URLs to parse
$url1 = 'https://www.example.net:443/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho?TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018%5fa%5f11%3a32%3a28&monta...'
$url2 = '?TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018%5fa%5f11%3a32%3a28&monta';

// Get the part after the "?"
$queryString1 = parse_url($url1)['query'] ?? ''; // 'query' may be undefined
$queryString2 = parse_url($url2)['query'] ?? ''; // 'query' may be undefined

// Split the parts into usable arrays and save the result into defined variables
$queryArray1 = $queryArray2 = [];
parse_str($queryString1, $queryArray1);
parse_str($queryString2, $queryArray2);

// Now you can manipulate the arrays as you wish;
// after you have done that, you can combine them together:
$resultQueryString = http_build_query(array_merge($queryArray1, $queryArray2));
```

Comment: `parse_url` returns an associative array, so I believe that should be : `parse_url($url1)['query']`, unless there is some new PHP feature that allows accessing an array key via object property syntax (that I'm not finding). Also, I am under the impression that the OP is getting back the full URL with the mangled query string, so they  need to split it first, which would mean having some confidence in where to split it, as there could be other legit url-encoded `?` in the query string. If the OP knows it will always start `?TPE`, then they can potentially split on that.

Comment: @Anthony You're absolutely right regarding the output of `parse_url`. I wrote everything out of my head, and unfortunately, I'm too much used to OOP (*ouch*). I adapted it accordingly. :) Regarding the other point, `parse_url` should do it's job in both scenarios. `['query']` simply returns everything after the first occurrence of `?` - at least that's as much I know and I'd expect it to do.

Comment: The only thing missing is how to combine the new query string with the original URL. Also, you may want to `unset($resultQueryString['ho?TPE']);`