# Rebuild url n php

Tags: php

I have this url : `https://www.example.net/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho?TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018_a_11%3a32%3a28&montant=53EUR`

and I must rebuild this url in (change `ho?TPE` by `ho&TPE`)

```
https://www.example.net/demo/index.php?order&desjardins&success&ho&TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018_a_11%3a32%3a28&montant=53EUR
```

I make this :

```
      $query = $_GET;
// replace parameter(s)
      $query['?'] = '&';
// rebuild url
      $query_result = http_build_query($query);
```

bu the result is : (`&ho%3FTPE`)

```
order=&desjardins=&success=&ho%3FTPE=monet14&date=12%2F07%2F2018_a_11%3A32%3A28&montant=53EUR
```

How to make to change `%3F` in `&`

and my last question I must have this at the final result

```
array(24) { ["order"]=> string(0) "" ["desjardins"]=> string(0) "" ["success"]=> string(0) "" ["ho"]=> string(0) "" ["TPE"]=> string(7) "monet14"
```

thank you

Comment: How is the URL built to begin with?

Comment: Don't repost the same question multiple times. If you need to clarify something, click the edit button underneath the question or add a comment either under your question or one of the answers.

Comment: @mike  the url is built by the bank. I just send this element : https://www.example.net/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho

Comment: What is the point of changing the URL? What actual problem are you solving by doing that?

Comment: @mike If I don't change the ? by &, I have a problem, because I come back allways on index.php . The correct url : https://www.example.net/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho&TPE=monet14date=12%2f07%2f2018_a_11%3a32%3a28&montant=53EUR allow me to finish the process.

Comment: What do you mean by "send the URL"? You send an HTTP request to the bank and one of the fields you send to the bank is that URL, and in the response the bank appends `?TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018%5fa%5f11%3a32%3a28&monta` to the URL you provide it? Is this correct?

Comment: @Mike : yes it's exact

Comment: @mike I have edited your original question then to make it less confusing. This one will likely be closed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the php "explode" function:

```
explode("&", $theurl);
```

You can manipulate the array from there and simply "implode" it back to your desired result:

[link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

[link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use can try `parse_url` in this case.

```
$url = 'https://www.example.net/demo/index.php?order&bank&success&ho?TPE=monet14&date=12%2f07%2f2018_a_11%3a32%3a28&montant=53EUR';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$parsed['query']  = str_replace('?', '&', $parsed['query']);
$url = implode('', $parsed);
```

Comment: You can't use implode there since it misses out the url schemes ://, it may miss out username passwords :, it will miss the ? in query, and the # in fragments